# CPLEX Optimization - Planning a sequence of products on a single machine

Tags: optimization, sequence, cplex, opl

Here's my problem. I have, let's say, 10 products to package. The packaging for all 10 products is done on the same line/machine.

There are different setup times between the different products. For example, the setup time from Product 1 to Product 2 (you have to adjust the height, and do a small cleanup) is 30mins. From Product 2 to Product 1 (you only have to adjust the height, no clean up), the setup time is 15 mins. From Product 1 to Product 3, it takes 5 mins, etc.

I'm trying to minimize the setup times.

How can I solve this? My actual problem has 100 different products (so a 100 by 100 matrix)

It's really similar to the Traveling Salesman Problem. The difference is that you don't absolutely have to leave from product 1 (or city A in the TSP) and you don't need to go back to product 1 at the end.

Here's a TSP code I used in the past. Can I modify it to solve my problem? Or is there any other way I can do it?

Thanks!

```
// ***********************
// Parameters
// ***********************

int     N       = ...;

range   V  = 1..N;

// arcs

tuple       arc        {int v_dep; int v_arr;}
setof(arc) A     = {<i,j> | i,j in V: i != j};

// Matrix Setup Time

float         D[V][V] = ...;

// ***********************
// Decision variable
// ***********************


// x [<i,j>]= 1 if node j follows i

dvar boolean x[A];

// flow conversion

dvar float+ y[A];


// ***********************
// Objective
// ***********************

// Minimize setup times

minimize sum (<i,j> in A) D[i][j]*x[<i,j>];




subject to {


 forall (v in V)

   sum (a in A: a.v_arr == v) x[a] == 1;


 forall (v in V)

   sum (a in A: a.v_dep == v) x[a] == 1;



 forall (v in V:v != 1)

 sum (a in A: a.v_arr == v) y[a]-sum (a in A: a.v_dep == v) y[a] == 1;


  sum (a in A: a.v_arr == 1) y[a]-sum (a in A: a.v_dep == 1) y[a] == -(N-1);

 forall (a in A)

 y[a] <= N*x[a];

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem, you can reduce it to TSP by creating a "Product 0", with cost 0 from Product 0 to Product i, and cost 0 from Product i to Product 0.

Then your packaging problem becomes a TSP that begins with "Product 0" and ends with it.